# Finding vlaues for $a>0,b >1$ s.t. that function $f'\left(x\right)$ exists for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to show all values for $a >0, b>1$ s.t. the function:
$$f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
ln(a+ln(b+x)) & x\geq0\\
\frac{xe^{x}}{2+e^{\frac{1}{x}}} & x<0
\end{cases}$$
Will be differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that the function is $f'(x)$ exists for all $x \neq 0$. So I tried to find those a,b by saying that:

$$f'\left(x\right)={\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}} \frac{f\left(x\right) -f\left(0\right)}{x-0}$$ 
exists iff
$${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}} \frac{f\left(x\right) -f\left(0\right)}{x}={\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{-}}} \frac{f\left(x\right) -f\left(0\right)}{x}$$

I also found that $f'_{+}\left(0\right) = \frac{1}{\left(a+lnb\right)b}$ but while trying to find $$f'_{+}\left(0\right) = {\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}} \frac{\frac{xe^{x}}{2+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}-ln\left(a+lnb\right)}{x}$$ 
But I don't know how to keep going from here. I  tried to think of ways to use L'Hopital's rule but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Any idea?

Comment: For $f$ to be differentiable at $0$, it first needs to be continuous at $0$. You didn't use that condition thus far.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you. That really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dixv helped me figure this out in the comment below:
So, when because $f$ is differentiable, $f$ is continuous. Therefore:
$$\lim_{x\to0^-} f\left(x\right)=\lim_{x\to0^+} f\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)$$
So we conclude $ln(a+ln(b)) = 0$. And thus $${{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\frac{xe^{x}}{2+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}-ln\left(a+ln\left(b\right)\right)}{x}}={\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\frac{xe^{x}}{2+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{e^{x}}{2+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}=\frac{1}{2}}}$$
From here finding a,b is easy.